# Receiving reply from Redis ZRANGE

Tags: node.js, redis

I currently have two sorted sets and I am trying to get all scores and members from one set and use it to remove members from the other set. The module that I am using is node_redis.

Right now I am trying to get the members and scores by calling `client.zrange()` and storing the reply in an array.

Am I correct in assuming the reply would be in array form? I realize the redis api says it returns a "Multi-bulk reply" but what does that mean exactly and how would I go about using it if it isn't an array?

I also have another question and that is can I use an array when using `zadd()`? 
An example would be like this.

```
client.zadd(historyKey, scores, members, function(err, reply){});
```

Where scores and members are arrays.

EDIT:

I am working with receiving and parsing SNMP Traps. Basically I receive a trap and check its alarm type. The useful information in these traps are the alarm type and the full trap name. I check to see if the alarm is a 0,1, or 2.

If it's a 1, then I store it in my Current sorted set at the unix time I received it. If it's a 0 or 2 I know that type of alarm is done and that I need to remove all traps like it from the Current set and put them into the History set along with the one I just received.

In order to remove the traps from the Current and put them into the History I had to create a separate set for each individual trap in order to keep track of where they would be located in the Current set.

That is if I receive the trap "RGB Gamut Error( ----Bb )" at time 1346276537 and store it in Current, I also store the exact score and member in a separate set with key "IPAddress:RGB Gamut Error".

That way when I receive alarm type 0 or 2 with the name "RGB Gamut Error" I can just append the IP Address to the front of it, go do `zrange` on that set, then add to History and remove from Current. And lastly delete the "IPAddress:RGB Gamut Error" set so I can start fresh.

Sidenote: My members actually have two numbers added to the end in order to make each member unique and not overwrite each other. This is really there only purpose.

Ex: IPAdress::RGB Gamut Error( Rr--Bb ):5:46

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in assuming the reply would be in array form?

Yes, `node_redis` will give you the reply from a `zrange` as an array.

> I also have another question and that is can I use an array when using zadd()? An example would be like this.

No. Before redis 2.4, you could only send one parameter at a time (so `zadd key score member`). Since redis 2.4, `zadd` (and many other commands) are *variadic*, i.e. they accept any number of parameters -- but not as an array. You still have to call it like this:

```
client.zadd(key, score1, member1, score2, member2, ..., function(err, reply){});
```

You could do some `.apply` trickery, but you would have to zip the `scores` and `members` arrays into one array first.

**Update:**

If you already have `scores` and `members` arrays, you could merge them into one array like this:

```
var scores = [1, 2, 3],
    members = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function merge (other) {
  return function (result, current, index) {
    result.push(current, other[index]);
    return result;
  }
}

var merged = scores.reduce(merge(members), []);

// Now merged = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c'];

var args = [key].concat(merged).concat(function(err, reply){});

client.zadd.apply(client, args);
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up calling `zrange` on one sorted set, parsing the reply array and storing the members and scores in separate arrays. Then I used those arrays to add to another sorted set. I need the members in a separate array anyway to remove those same members from yet another sorted set, three in total. Though I am concerned that parsing the reply array might take too much time if it is a large sorted set. Would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: It's hard to say if there is a better way, unless you tell us more about what you are actually trying to to. That is, perhaps you could model your data in a different way. Apart from that, if you could settle for a release candidate, you might be able to handle it all in a Lua script.

Comment: I edited my question to include exactly what I am doing and maybe this will help you help me to come up with a different way to model my data, if a better way exists. Also I need to do this in Redis so I am limited by only using it.

Comment: Thanks @RoyValentine! I still don't totally get it. It seems that you describe your current solution, and not the problem you are trying to solve. In any case, I recommend you send an e-mail to the [Redis mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db) -- there are a number of very knowledgeable Redis users who are happy to help. Just make sure to state your *problem* clearly, and I'm sure you will get a few suggestions.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your input. I came up with another solution but still don't know if it's the best. I'll definitely send them an email stating my problem.